# VPN from Windows 10 Client to Cisco RV325 SOHO Router

Tags: networking, vpn

I can connect to my home network, which is behind a Cisco RV325 router, from iOS via a VPN without any problem (well, it took a long time to figure out what the various configuration parameters of IPSec were, but after I did it was easy). I use a pre-shared key.

But I cannot get a VPN connection set up from Windows 10 (latest updated version).

In iOS, the terms "Group Name", "Account" and "Secret" refer to the EasyVPN connection name, the user name I've set up on the RV325 and the pre-shared key.

But in Windows 10 when I enter the pre-shared key in the pre-shared key field, the connection name in the connection name field and the user name in the user id field...it won't connect.

I get a not very helpful error message that "the L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during initial negotiations with the remote computer".

I wondered if maybe this meant the encryption algorithms specified on the RV325 didn't match what Windows was using...but I don't see any way in Windows to change them.

Suggestions? Other than doing all my VPN work on my iPhone :)?

**Additional Info**

Cisco RV325 configuration info. Note that I have two VPNs defined, one EasyVPN and one GroupVPN. The iOS connection goes through the EasyVPN. I used to be able to connect, using Greenbow's client app, to the GroupVPN connection...but something has changed, and I can't get that connection to work anymore. My goal is still to get a "regular" Windows 10 VPN to work.

Summary VPN screen

[image]

EasyVPN Configuration (works with iOS)

[image]

GroupVPN (used to work with Greenbox, but not anymore)

[image]

User Configuration

[image]

Comment: You can certainly configure Windows 10 to connect to the VPN if your iPhone can. Without seeing your actual settings it’s nothing but a guess for us. There are all kinds of advanced options for a VPN connection but you are probably stuck in the modern VPN interface and not seeing them. Read here for how you actually configure a VPN connection. I actually think this Windows 10 change is  pretty lame. https://it.clas.ufl.edu/kb/windows-10-vpn/ just match up the proper settings and go.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, you can’t right click the start menu and get to the classic control panel anymore like the instructions above suggest. Just click start and start typing “control panel,” and it will come up.

Comment: Thanx, @Appleoddity. More info added. Short version: even after following the directions the connection still failed.